# Kafka Streams vs Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams, avro

I wrote an application that reads 100.000 Avro records per second from Kafka topic, aggregates by key, use tumbling windows with 5 different sizes, do some calculation to know the highest, lowest, initial and end value, and write back to another Kafka topic.

This application already exists in Flink, but the source is RSocket in CSV format and the sink is Cassandra. The problem is that the new application is using a lot more CPU and memory. I checked [this article](https://www.confluent.io/de-de/blog/apache-flink-apache-kafka-streams-comparison-guideline-users/) and noticed performance is not mentioned.

Am I correct to assume the difference is mostly because of Avro serialisation / deserialisation, or is Flink supposed to be faster for this use case? If the difference is small, I'd prefer Kafka Streams to avoid needing to manage the cluster.

Comment: This is almost one of those "which is better, x or y" questions that SO disallows. I would add more details about your Flink setup, with a specific question like "how can I reduce memory & CPU requirements to be closer to (whatever you think is reasonable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this question can be answered generally. Both Flink and Kafka Streaming can be tuned to the workload, and small changes in parameters can make a large difference in performance. Generally, there is no fundamental reason why Flink should be a lot faster for such a use case than Kafka Streams. One exception may be repartitioning, which always need to go through the Kafka cluster for Kafka streams and can stay within the cluster for Flink, but as I understand, you are not repartitioning in your use case.

Serialization format may play a large role, however. Some benchmarks that I remember for protobuf (for avro is similar) showed that the size in (Java) memory is 100x larger than the serialized data on the wire. Again, this depends on many things, in particular how nested/complex your schema is. If avro is deserialized to a complex object model, this will cause a significant CPU / memory overhead compared to passing strings around.

However, the only way to tell for certain what is slowing down your use case is profiling it and seeing where the additional resources are spent.

Comment: Source for "data is 100x larger"? Are you comparing native Java serializable objects to the others?

Answer (score 0):

Without benchmarks on your own hardware, or JVM profiling your code, it's hard to say which will be faster.

Flink does invoke more JVM function calls than Kafka Streams, from what I've seen.

Kafka Streams doesn't work well (or at all) with external systems such as RSocket or Cassandra. Therefore, you would still need Flink or some other ETL tool like Kafka Connect (i.e manage a cluster) to get data into a Kafka topic to then process, regardless of framework.

Serialization format shouldn't matter. Flink or Kafka Streams will use the exact same JVM methods from Avro (or any other format) SDK.

Comment: The source and sink will be Kafka in the end. I just want to know if Flink is supposed to be more resource efficient when performing this kind of stateful stream processing (aggregation and windowing)

Comment: Like I said, that'll be up for you to benchmark. But based on my experience with Flink call stacks and network overhead, then no.